# Only Select First Reverse Duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, subquery

I have the following table in a SQL Server 2014 database:

```
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| ID | CODE  | NUMBER | BALANCE |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 1  | B0001 | 122960 | 100.00  |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 2  | B0001 | 123168 | -100.00 |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 3  | B0001 | 121400 | 500.00  |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 4  | T0001 | 19755  | 50.00   |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 5  | T0001 | 19975  | -50.00  |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 6  | T0001 | 122202 | 50.00   |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| 7  | T0001 | 122203 | 50.00   |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
```

I am trying to select rows where the balances for a given code can be offset against another row and totaled to 0. For example, the balance on rows 1 and 2 sum to 0 so should be returned. I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT T1.NUMBER
FROM TABLE T1, TABLE T2
WHERE T1.CODE = T2.CODE
AND T1.BALANCE + T2.BALANCE = 0
```

This works OK for code B0001. It will return rows 1 and 2 which cancel each other out and ignore row 3. I'm having a problem with code T0001 because the query I'm using will match each of the 3 positive values with the negative value and return all rows associated with that code. I only want it to return rows 4 and 5 for T0001.

Comment: So you want the net to be 0 ONLY for consecutive IDs right?

Comment: I don't care about the IDs. I just want the NUMBER values where they can be cancelled off. For T0001, it wouldn't matter which number it returned to cancel the negative value as long is it only returns one pair of values. For example, for T0001 it could return rows 4 and 5, 5 and 6, or 5 and 7. They would all be valid but I only want one of them.

Comment: Please see my answer, it provides a simple workaround with Group by clause, please let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/* DATASET MOCK-UP */
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( ID INT, CODE VARCHAR(10), NUMBER INT, BALANCE DECIMAL(18,2) );
INSERT INTO @Data ( ID, CODE, NUMBER, BALANCE ) VALUES
( 1, 'B0001', 122960 , 100.00 ),
( 2, 'B0001', 123168 , -100.00 ),
( 3, 'B0001', 121400 , 500.00 ),
( 4, 'T0001', 19755  , 50.00 ),
( 5, 'T0001', 19975  , -50.00 ),
( 6, 'T0001', 122202 , 50.00 ),
( 7, 'T0001', 122203 , 50.00 );

/*
    Return records where combined balances equal 0 by adding the
    current record's BALANCE against its previous (lag) or following (lead) balances.
*/
SELECT
    ID, CODE, NUMBER, BALANCE, ( BALANCE + LAG_BALANCE ) AS LAG_BALANCE, ( BALANCE + LEAD_BALANCE ) AS LEAD_BALANCE
FROM (
    
    SELECT
        ID,
        CODE,
        NUMBER,
        BALANCE,
        LAG ( BALANCE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS LAG_BALANCE, 
        LEAD ( BALANCE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS LEAD_BALANCE 
    FROM @Data

) AS Results
WHERE
    BALANCE + LAG_BALANCE = 0
    OR
    BALANCE + LEAD_BALANCE = 0
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

Returns

```
+----+-------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | CODE  | NUMBER | BALANCE | LAG_BALANCE | LEAD_BALANCE |
+----+-------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | B0001 | 122960 | 100.00  | 100.00      | 0.00         |
|  2 | B0001 | 123168 | -100.00 | 0.00        | 400.00       |
|  4 | T0001 |  19755 | 50.00   | 550.00      | 0.00         |
|  5 | T0001 |  19975 | -50.00  | 0.00        | 0.00         |
|  6 | T0001 | 122202 | 50.00   | 0.00        | 100.00       |
+----+-------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

**UPDATE:**
*I just want the NUMBER values where they can be cancelled off. For T0001, it wouldn't matter which number it returned to cancel the negative value as long is it only returns one pair of values. For example, for T0001 it could return rows 4 and 5, 5 and 6, or 5 and 7. They would all be valid but I only want one of them.*

This edit returns a single NUMBER for each CODE that matches your "zero-out" condition:

```
SELECT
    CODE, MIN ( NUMBER ) AS MIN_NUMBER
FROM (
    
    SELECT
        ID,
        CODE,
        NUMBER,
        BALANCE,
        LAG ( BALANCE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS LAG_BALANCE, 
        LEAD ( BALANCE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS LEAD_BALANCE 
    FROM @Data

) AS Results
WHERE
    BALANCE + LAG_BALANCE = 0
    OR
    BALANCE + LEAD_BALANCE = 0
GROUP BY
    CODE
ORDER BY
    CODE;
```

Returns

```
+-------+------------+
| CODE  | MIN_NUMBER |
+-------+------------+
| B0001 |     122960 |
| T0001 |      19755 |
+-------+------------+
```

**UPDATE #2:**

```
/*
    Return the first TWO rows for a CODE with BALANCEs that zero-out each other.
*/
SELECT
    ID, CODE, NUMBER, BALANCE, ( BALANCE + LAG_BALANCE ) AS LAG_BALANCE, ( BALANCE + LEAD_BALANCE ) AS LEAD_BALANCE
FROM (
    
    SELECT
        ID,
        CODE,
        NUMBER,
        BALANCE,
        LAG ( BALANCE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS LAG_BALANCE, 
        LEAD ( BALANCE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS LEAD_BALANCE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE, ID ) AS CODE_ROW
    FROM @Data

) AS Results
WHERE
    CODE_ROW <= 2
    AND ( BALANCE + LAG_BALANCE = 0 OR BALANCE + LEAD_BALANCE = 0 )
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

Returns

```
+----+-------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | CODE  | NUMBER | BALANCE | LAG_BALANCE | LEAD_BALANCE |
+----+-------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | B0001 | 122960 | 100.00  | 100.00      | 0.00         |
|  2 | B0001 | 123168 | -100.00 | 0.00        | 400.00       |
|  4 | T0001 |  19755 | 50.00   | 50.00       | 0.00         |
|  5 | T0001 |  19975 | -50.00  | 0.00        | 0.00         |
+----+-------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are doing here. I only want to return any two rows for T0001 which combine to give a balance of 0. You result gives three rows. Can you clarify?

Comment: My resultset has two rows that are returned in the (UPDATED) example I provided, not three, so I'm not sure how you're getting three. Basically, the subquery adds the current record's BALANCE to the CODE's corresponding LAG or LEAD records which the outer query then uses to perform math to return any rows where the current balance plus either the lag or lead balance zero each other out. The GROUP BY CODE and MIN returns a single NUMBER value for each respective CODE, which, if I understand your question, is that you were looking for.

Comment: You stated: " For example, for T0001 it could return rows 4 and 5, 5 and 6, or 5 and 7. They would all be valid but I only want **one** of them" You actually want the first TWO matching rows? Your request isn't very clear.

Comment: @Chesterfield Check out my **UPDATE #2**. I think I have a better understanding of what you want.

Comment: This works but if I change row 5 to be positive and row 6 to be negative, then it only returns one row for T0001. I am using GMB's answer above. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match rows on opposite balance, but each row should be matched only once.

An option is to enumerate the rows with `row_number()` first. You can then use the self-join solution, adding the row number in the join condition. I prefer `not exists` - but the logic is the same:

```
with  cte as (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by code, balance order by id) rn
    from mytable t
)
select *
from cte c
where exists (
    select 1 
    from cte c1 
    where c1.code = c.code and c1.rn = c.rn and c1.balance + c.balance = 0
)
order by code, id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1c994417d9fa1dd754701313f30ac576)**:

```
id | code  | number | balance | rn
-: | :---- | -----: | ------: | -:
 1 | B0001 | 122960 |  100.00 |  1
 2 | B0001 | 123168 | -100.00 |  1
 4 | T0001 |  19755 |   50.00 |  1
 5 | T0001 |  19975 |  -50.00 |  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
;with 
neg_cte as (select *, row_number() over(partition by code, balance order by id) rn 
            from @Data where BALANCE<0),
pos_cte as (select *, row_number() over(partition by code, balance order by id) rn 
            from @Data where BALANCE>0)
select * from neg_cte
union all
select pc.* from neg_cte nc join pos_cte pc on nc.CODE=pc.CODE
                                            and nc.BALANCE=pc.BALANCE*-1
                                            and nc.rn=pc.rn
order by ID;
```

Results

```
ID  CODE    NUMBER  BALANCE rn
1   B0001   122960  100.00  1
2   B0001   123168  -100.00 1
4   T0001   19755   50.00   1
5   T0001   19975   -50.00  1
```